# Horizontal Bar-Chart in angular-chart.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, chart.js, angular-chart, angular-chartist.js

I have successfully created a bar chart in angular-chart.js but now I want to change it into a horizontal bar chart. Also, I would like the fields to be placed inside of the horizontal bar itself:

**code**

```
 angular.module("app", ["chart.js"])
    .controller("LineCtrl", function ($scope) {

    var x =
    {
        "labels": [
            "Monday",
            "Tuesday",
            "Wednesday",
            "Thursday",
            "Friday",
            "Saturday",
            "Sunday"
        ],
        "data": [
            99,
            59,
            80,
            81,
            56,
            55,
            40
        ],
        "type": "line",
        "series": "eventTypePerDay"
    }

    console.log(x.series);
    //ses all of the variables to build the chart
    $scope.labels = x.labels;
    $scope.colours = ['#71d078'];
    $scope.type = x.type;
    $scope.data = [x.data];
    $scope.series = [x.series];


});
```

**example of what I want**

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Under the hood angular-chart.js uses chart.js, which does not have native support for horizontal bar charts.  That said, there is a horizontal bar chart plugin that can be added to support this type of chart:  https://github.com/tomsouthall/Chart.HorizontalBar.js

I believe that to make this work, you will need to use the dynamic chart directive

```
<canvas id="base" class="chart-base" chart-type="type"
  chart-data="data" chart-labels="labels" chart-legend="true">
</canvas>
```

And then specify the type as `HorizontalBar`.

Comment: @user2402107 Hello can you tell me how did you get it working, i havent been able to. Thank you.

Comment: Here's the example on github:  https://github.com/tomsouthall/Chart.HorizontalBar.js/blob/master/samples/horizontal-bar.html

Comment: exactly what grdneault said

Comment: Even using the example (and running the project locally) I couldn't get this to work. Sad day... am I missing something?

Comment: Update:   the source URL of chart.js needed to be changed and the syntax of how you create a chart needed to be changed.

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js@2.8.0"></script>

Answer (score 5):

for those wondering here later; there are new versions of chart.js and angular-chart.js available. Chart.js 2.1 and later support horizontal charts, angular-chart.js has a new branch to work with the latest chart.js version [see the github repo here](https://github.com/jtblin/angular-chart.js/tree/chartjs-2.0).

Using this version does not require the above mentioned HorizontalBar plugin by Tom Southall.

Use the samples available at the above angular-chart.js site, and make sure to set the value of the class attribute to "chart-horizontalBar".

```
<canvas id="HorizontalBar" class="chart chart-horizontalBar" chart-data="data" chart-labels="labels" chart-series="series"></canvas>
```

Comment: above link not found

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there is a need to include **Chart.HorizontalBar.js** now. This is how to get a simple horizontal bar chart in Angular using chart.js-

HTML-

```
<div>
    <canvas id="bar-chart-horizontal" width="800" height="450"></canvas>
</div>
```

JS controller-

```
var myChart = new Chart(document.getElementById("bar-chart-horizontal"), {
        type: 'horizontalBar',
        data: {
          labels: ["Africa", "Asia", "Europe", "Latin America", "North America"],
          datasets: [
            {
              label: "Population (millions)",
              backgroundColor: ["#ff0000", "#8e5ea2","#3cba9f","#454545","#c45850"],
              data: [2478,5267,734,784,433]
            }
          ]
        },
        options: {
          legend: { display: false },
          title: {
            display: true,
            text: 'Predicted world population (millions) in 2050'
          }
        }
    });
```